# Merging multiple arrays using only <stidio.h> & <stdlib.h>

Tags: c, arrays

I am required to build a function that merges 3 sorted arrays of integers into a singular sorted array using only stdio.h and stdlib.h. I am unable to figure out how to build one with limits.h and I am as of yet unable to figure out how to modify it to run with limits.h or build a code from scratch that can perform the task. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

This is my code with limits.h:

```
int multimerge(
int * const * const arrays,      // arrays holding the data
int const * const arraysizes,    // sizes of the arrays in `arrays`
int number_of_arrays,            // number of arrays
int * const output               // pointer to output buffer
){
    int i = 0;       // output cursor
    int j = 0;       // index for minimum search
    int min;         // minimum in this iteration
    int minposition; // position of the minimum

    // cursor for the arrays
    int * cursor = calloc(number_of_arrays,sizeof(int));

    if(cursor == NULL)
        return -1;

    while(1){
        min = INT_MAX;
        minposition = -1; // invalid position

        // Go through the current positions and get the minimum
        for(j = 0; j < number_of_arrays; ++j){

            if(cursor[j] < arraysizes[j] &&  // ensure that the cursor is still valid
               arrays[j][cursor[j]] < min){  // the element is smaller
                min = arrays[j][cursor[j]];  // save the minimum ...
                minposition = j;             // ... and its position
            }
        }

        // if there is no minimum, then the position will be invalid

        if(minposition == -1)
            break;

        // update the output and the specific cursor            
        output[i++] = min;
        cursor[minposition]++;
    }
    free(cursor);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here and how limits.h is relevant to your problem?

Comment: I am  required to build a function with only stdio.h and stdlib.h. however I can't figure out how without limits.h which I am not allowed to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

limits.sh needs to be included only if you use any constants from the header file. In your program, you are using INT_MAX. If you use your own constants then you need not use from the header file. But you need to define your constants based on the size of the data types or some max values based on your requirement.